# Overlapping div's (yes, again!)

Tags: html, overlay, overlap

I'm building a product configurator.
I need 2 images to overlap. Imagine a stove, where the stove itself is one image, and the knobs / handles another.

Both images are the same size, so they should overlap "fully".
Both images are inside a div and based on a function that returns a div.append(Child) if that matters.

I have tried every way I found online, doing what I think is right but it obviously doesnt work. If I call 1 div then the other (img1img2), they dont overlap. If I call the second image inside the first div, it doesnt show.
What am I doing wrong?!
html:

```
    <input type="button" onclick="create_img(); " value="Create image" />
    <div class="imageWrapper">
    <div id="pop" >
    <div id="pop2" >
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    function create_img(){


var im=""
var div = document.getElementById("pop");
var hold= document.createElement("img");

if (document.Lacanche_Configurator.Range.value=="1" && document.Lacanche_Configurator.Range_color.value=="12" ){im= "http://www.french-barn.com/configurator/img_front/cormatin/jauneprovence.jpg" ;}
else if (document.Lacanche_Configurator.Range.value=="1" && document.Lacanche_Configurator.Range_color.value=="13" ){im= "http://www.french-barn.com/attachments/Image/Lacanche/Ranges_front/Chagny1800-trans.png" ;}
else {im="http://technofriends.files.wordpress.com/2008/03/google_logo_.jpg";}

hold.src=im;
hold.border=0;
div.appendChild(hold);

var im2=""
var div = document.getElementById("pop2");
var hold= document.createElement("img");

if (document.Lacanche_Configurator.Finishes.value=="1" ){im2= "http://www.french-barn.com/configurator/img_front/cormatin/laitonbrillant.png" ;}
else {im2="http://technofriends.files.wordpress.com/2008/03/google_logo_.jpg";}

hold.src=im2;
hold.border=0;
div.appendChild(hold);
}
```

CSS:

```
    .imageWrapper{
            position: relative;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            width:160px;
            }


            #pop {
            background:transparent;
            }


            #pop2 {
            position: absolute;
            left:0;
            top: -150px;
            background:transparent;

            }
```

i have tried so many ways, not sure what to do next!!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to stack 2 images, then you should be able to do this using a single `<IMG/>` tag.  Set the CSS background-image of the `<IMG/>` tag to be the picture of the stove.  Then set the `src` attribute of the `<IMG/>` tag to be the knobs.

Comment: Thanks David. I am not sure if I can use img tags given that each image is created by a function, but your answer inspired me to do the same thing within the function itself. It worked.

Answer (score 0):

so, following David's advice and doing more research on the proper syntax, this is what I came up with.
the function creates both images (im amd im2) according to parameters as listed, then one is defined as the bg image, and the other as the src image.
so it looks like i dont really need css for this particular issue.

Thanks again, David! saved me a lot of time, headaches and money by having someone else design that for me!

```
function create_img(){


                var im=""
                var div = document.getElementById("pop");
                var hold= document.createElement("img");

                if (document.Lacanche_Configurator.Range.value=="1" && document.Lacanche_Configurator.Range_color.value=="12" ){im= "http://www.french-barn.com/configurator/img_front/cormatin/jauneprovence.jpg" ;}
                else if (document.Lacanche_Configurator.Range.value=="1" && document.Lacanche_Configurator.Range_color.value=="13" ){im= "http://www.french-barn.com/attachments/Image/Lacanche/Ranges_front/Chagny1800-trans.png" ;}
                else {im="http://technofriends.files.wordpress.com/2008/03/google_logo_.jpg";}

                var im2=""
                var div = document.getElementById("pop");
                var hold= document.createElement("img");

                if (document.Lacanche_Configurator.Finishes.value=="1" ){im2= "http://www.french-barn.com/configurator/img_front/cormatin/laitonbrillant.png" ;}
                else if (document.Lacanche_Configurator.Finishes.value=="2" ){im2= "http://www.french-barn.com/configurator/img_front/cormatin/nickel.png" ;}
                else {im2="http://technofriends.files.wordpress.com/2008/03/google_logo_.jpg";}

                hold.src=im2;
                hold.border=0;
                div.appendChild(hold);
                div.style.backgroundImage = 'url("'+im+'")';


                }
```